# JHipster: Redirect root domain to www

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jhipster

I am working on Search Engine Optimization and I would like https://pomzen.com to be redirected to https://www.pomzen.com.

Is it possible to do it in a JHipster project, or is it done outside of the project? For example in DNS records or web config for Tomcat?

Comment: I solved this by creating a new App Service in Azure with the only purpose of redirecting. The only drawback is that that the service is not free, so it would be good to know if there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Redirects have to be done at the web server level. Basically you need the web server to send an HTTP Redirect (302 or 301). DNS cannot help you here.

Note : There are some hosted DNS platforms that have workarounds (Google Domains, Cloudflare). But they will not be able to handle HTTPS redirects.

Answer (score 0):

#### Redirect root domain to `www` using `web.xml` config of Tomcat

1. Create a project, which then be compiled to the `jar` library

   ```
   tomcat-redirect
   │
   ├── src
   │   └── main
   │       └── java
   │           └── TomcatRedirect.java
   └── pom.xml
   ```
2. Configure `maven-compiler-plugin` and `compile-time` dependencies

   ```xml
   <build>
     <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <source>7</source>
           <target>7</target>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>

   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
3. In Java code implement `javax.servlet.Filter` and configure `301 redirect`

   ```java
   public class TomcatRedirect implements Filter {
     @Override
     public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                   FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

       String domainName = "localhost";
       String requestURL =
               ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString();

       if (!requestURL.contains("www." + domainName)) {
         String newRequestURL =
                 requestURL.replace(domainName, "www." + domainName);

         ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(301);
         ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Location", newRequestURL);

         System.out.println("Request: " + requestURL +
                 " was redirected to: " + newRequestURL);
       }
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
     }
   }
   ```
4. Build project to the `jar` file using `Maven` package goal in your IDE

   [image: TomcatRedirect.java]
5. Copy `jar` file into Tomcat `lib` folder
6. Add filter registration and mapping to the Tomcat `web.xml` in it's `conf` folder

   ```xml
   <!-- =========================== Filter ================================= -->

   <filter>
       <filter-name>TomcatRedirect</filter-name>
       <filter-class>TomcatRedirect</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>TomcatRedirect</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>

   <!-- =========================== Filter ================================= -->
   ```

---

<sup>Works for: **tomcat-9.0.33**</sup>